# return records that appears more than one in one field in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id|unique no| contract
1 |uniqNo1  | 248/2002 
2 |uniqNo2  | 248/2002 
3 |uniqNo3  | 32/65/129 
4 |uniqNo4  | 39/654
5 |uniqNo5  | 635/2001
6 |uniqNo6  | 635/2001
7 |uniqNo7  | 635/2001
8 |uniqNo8  | 35/2002   
9 |uniqNo9  | 35/2002   
10|uniqNo10 | 48/2001   
11|uniqNo11 | 987/2001
```

I am trying to create a select statement in access that will return only those records that have more than one contract.

I tried many ways but I couldn’t find something.

If someone can give me some idea just to start from somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you could provide your SQL with what you tried so someone could find your problem easier..

Comment: Please add a result set you wish

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable T
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM yourtable T2
    WHERE T.contract = T2.contract
) > 1
```

Comment: Basically I want to distinct count all the records. I tried with the max but nothing happened.